# Scroll event is firing after jquery animate function was done

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEvqOp) is the example.

If you check the console you will notice that `Scroll Fired` is logged several times during the scroll animation and once the animation is done the callback function is called and `ANIMATION DONE` is logged. However, after that there is one more `Scroll Fired` log.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Logically speaking the reason behind it probably is that, since javascript can't fire two functions at the same time this is what happens: on the last scroll it calls the `onComplete` function first, then since a scroll happened it triggers the scroll even handler. To get rid of it follow the answer below as it seems like a good method to do it! Otherwise you'd have to find a way to fire the event handler before the `onComplete()` during the last scroll.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix for your problem can be the following

```
var child = $('#container');
var onComplete = function () {
    completed = true;
    console.log('ANIMATION DONE');
};

var completed = false;
child.animate({scrollLeft: 50}, 300, onComplete);

child.scroll(function () {
  if (!completed)
    console.log('Scroll Fired');
});
```

I just added a variable which shows if the animation has been completed in order to stop the scroll event code.

Comment: The only downside to this solution is that, once the animation is completed and you manually scroll the `div` it won't trigger the event, what I would do is reset the flag at the end, either in an else where it resets it only when the flag is set to false or reset it whenever the function is called, at the end of the function.